# How can i search for \r\n in an SQL SELECT LIKE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, select, line-breaks

I'm working on a site for a client who did not properly sanitize some of their form data.  In particular, they did not do anything to account for line-breaks received from textareas.  So, in hundreds of db rows there are `\r\n` and `\r\n\r\n` and `\r\n\r\n\r\n`... you get the idea.  I need to somehow extract only the rows which have `\r\n` to clean up the data.  I can't for the life of my though, build a query which selects these rows!  I realize that I must need to escape the slash somehow, but I'm not doing so successfully.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT Id,Description FROM lakes WHERE Description LIKE '%\r\n%';
SELECT Id,Description FROM lakes WHERE Description LIKE '%\\r\\n%';
SELECT Id,Description FROM lakes WHERE Description LIKE '%\\\r\\\n%';
SELECT Id,Description FROM lakes WHERE Description LIKE '%\\\\r\\\\n%';
```

I can of course continue to add slashes, but I feel like I'm probably missing something important if 4 slashes isn't doing the trick.

Each of these queries returns results, but none of the results are ever the one's with the `\r\n` in them.  The last query (with 4 slashes) did return 2 rows which did have the `\r\n`, along with 138 additional rows which didn't.

Also, because I know someone will mention it, I do know about `nl2br()`.  For some reason it is not working with the raw data from the table.  For now, I would be happy being able to pull these rows and clean them up.

Thanks in advance!

Josh

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but then again, what's wrong with the first query? Are these the lines without `\r\n` sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of something that SQL really isn't good at.

Using PHP write a simple script that returns all the rows ( or 20 rows at a time) and use a php regular expression to find the ones you are after.  Then do whatever you want with the data and update the database.  SQL isn't sophisticated enough to do what you want, its much easier to do in PHP.

Comment: That makes sense. I can process it outside in PHP. Do you have any idea why the nl2br() function wouldn't work with the raw data from the database?

Comment: I think there is something funny going on since I cant see any reason nl2br wouldnt work.

Comment: if there are extra \\ then its not a \r\n its a \\r\\n which is different :)

Comment: In the database, they are all \r\n, with no extra slashes... The weird thing is, I can do a plain pull on a blank page and not have it work either.  Oh well, this probably belongs as a separate question.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql you can use:

```
SELECT Id,Description FROM lakes WHERE Description LIKE E'%\r\n%';
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html:

> PostgreSQL also accepts “escape” string constants, which are an
>   extension to the SQL standard. An escape string constant is specified
>   by writing the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening
>   single quote, e.g., E'foo'. (When continuing an escape string constant
>   across lines, write E only before the first opening quote.) Within an
>   escape string, a backslash character () begins a C-like backslash
>   escape sequence, in which the combination of backslash and following
>   character(s) represent a special byte value

Answer (score 0):

```
[Description] LIKE '%'+CHAR(10)+'%'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code might be a solution for the problem at hand, it is advisable that you add some context to it, at least a brief explanation.